# Neo4j: Check condition between all consecutive relations in path

Tags: neo4j, cypher, sliding-window

I want to query all paths of arbitrary length

```
(a)-[:Relation*]->(b)
```

where for each pair `(r1, r2)` of consecutive relationships

```
()-[r1]->()-[r2]->()
```

a condition, say `r2.foo > r1.foo`, is met.

You can imagine `foo` being a timestamp and I only want to find paths where all steps are in chronological order.

---

What I currently have is this:

```
MATCH path = ()-[:Relationship*]->()
WITH rels(path) AS rels, path
WHERE reduce(acc = { inOrder: true, previous: rels[0] }, r IN tail(rels) |
    { inOrder: acc.inOrder AND r.foo > acc.previous.foo, previous: r }).inOrder
RETURN path
```

Now, this seems to work. However, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient query. Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually do it, by playing with the `ALL` predicate on the size of the relationships collection of the path, example :

```
MATCH p=(a:Cool)-[*]->(c) 
WHERE ALL ( x IN range(1, length(p)-1) WHERE (rels(p)[x]).i > (rels(p)[x-1]).i ) 
AND length(p) > 1
RETURN p
```

The `i` property in my query would be your relationship's timestamp property

Working example here :

http://console.neo4j.org/r/2bzo4m

Comment: Thanks! I assume this is more efficient because `ALL` can short circuit? Small nitpick: Paths of length 1 are allowed as they are chronological by definition.

Comment: No it needs to traverse every path, if you need fast computations, a more deeper thought about your model depending on your use case is to be done, there is none model to fit them all ;-)

Comment: @KirillRakhman In Neo4j 3.1 the ALL will be applied as predicate and not as filter ;-) https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/7294

Comment: Good to know. Is there a timeline for the 3.1 release?

Comment: RC1 soon, GA end of the year